# Is it possible to use ext4 native encryption for encrypting home directory?

Tags: encryption, ext4, ecryptfs

ext4 filesystem supports encryption since kernel 4.1. Currently, Ubuntu uses ecryptfs for encrypting home directory. Is it possible to use ext4 native encryption for encrypted home directory? (Just to not put an additional layer and service folders over the filesystem.)

Comment: This would be great for performance reasons.

Comment: Now instructions available at arch wiki - https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fscrypt
Not tried it yet, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no distro integration of ext4 encryption in Ubuntu as of now. That will hopefully change by 17.10, with full support of ext4 encryption being used for home directory encryption by Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Have any announcements/links about Ubuntu switching away from eCryptFS to ext4 encryption for homes? Google's not being very forthcoming with *"ubuntu using ext4 encryption for home"* and it seems like a pretty big change to be quietly set for next year

Comment: Probably should make a point of checking on Launchpad and if nothing comes up, then file a feature request.